# Parse string between " characters ANTLR4

Tags: parsing, antlr4

My task is to write grammar for custom query language, where users can write some basic queries.
My grammar so far:

```
grammar                 EAQL;

prog:                   cond;

cond:                   cond logical_operator cond | elexpr comparison_operator  VALUE;

elexpr:                 ELSTEREOTYPE '.' eattribute;

conexpr:                CSTEREOTYPE '.' cattribute;

eattribute:             'Name' | 'Path' | 'GUID' | conexpr;

cattribute:             'Name' | 'GUID' | elexpr;

VALUE:                   QUOTATION ( ~([QUOTATION]) | ~('\n'))+ QUOTATION;

ELSTEREOTYPE:           'EG_ApplicationComponent' | 'EG_ApplicationFunction';

CSTEREOTYPE:            'EG_Flow';

SPACE:                  ' ';

QUOTATION:              '"';

EOL:                    '\n';

WS : (' ' | '\t')+ -> channel(HIDDEN);

AND:                    'AND';

OR:                     'OR';

logical_operator:       AND | OR;

EQUALS:                 '=';

GREATER_THAN:           '>';

SMALLER_THAN:           '<';

comparison_operator:    GREATER_THAN | SMALLER_THAN | EQUALS;
```

When i try to parse this string

> EG_ApplicationComponent.Name= "name1" AND EG_ApplicationFunction.Name="name2"

ANTLR will create following children in tree:

1. 'EG_ApplicationComponent'
2. '.'
3. 'Name'
4. '='
5. '"name1" AND EG_ApplicationFunction.Name= "name2"'

I am absolute beginner in creating parsers, but i still do not understand why it does greedy matching until end of string in VALUE, when I specified that matching should end when QUOTATION is found. I expect, that if would match 'name1' as VALUE in first branch of tree and then create another branch with EG_ApplicationFunction.Name= "name2" parsed as previous branch.

This would be my expected result:

1. 'EG_ApplicationComponent'
2. '.'
3. 'Name'
4. '='
5. '"name1"'
6. AND
7. EG_ApplicationFunction
8. '.'
9. 'Name'
10. '='
11. '"name2"'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~[QUOTATION]` matches any character other than `Q`, `U`, `O`, `T`, `A`, `T`, `I`, `O` and `N`. What you need to do is `~["]`.

Your `VALUE` rule could look like this:

```
VALUE
 : QUOTATION ~["\r\n]* QUOTATION
 ;
```

Comment: Thanks, it finally did something, and parsed correct value 'name1' but after that string ' AND EG_ApplicationFunction.Name= "name2"' was ignored.

Comment: We found out that parsing was incorrect because there were whitespaces in our input, but it was fixed when we added it into language declaration, in AND:     ' AND ';

OR:      ' OR ';